# Passing universal pointer class to functions

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, c++11, smart-pointers

I am trying to implement a universal pointer class, which holds eighter a raw pointer or a `shared_ptr`. I have an enum to indicate what the pointer object holds.

```
enum class memory_management_t{
    raw_pointer,
    counted_pointer,
};
```

the pointer class is a template class:

```
template<class T, memory_management_t MEM>
class pointer;
```

which overloads the `->` and `*` -operators.
Now my question is if a virtual member function of a class wants to use the pointer class like this:

```
void func(pointer<std::string> s);
```

Since func could be virtual, this would not be possible:

```
template<memory_management_t MEM>
void func(pointer<std::string, MEM> s);
```

It would be nice if I could pass pointers to functions without overloading those functions, no mather if they are `pointer<T, memory_management_t::raw_pointer>` or `pointer<T,memory_management_t::counted_pointer>`

How can I achieve this efficient?

Comment: _"This all is for educational purposes only so please don't suggest me to change my design or say doing this is a bad idea in c++."_ Well, what do you expect??

Comment: Have a look into the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), there might be solutions offered from going that direction.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am sorry I just don't want answers like "just dont do this at all" of cause I will change my design if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason to have such a pointer class is if you want to be able to, at runtime, pass owned or unowned memory to a function/object. In which case, what determines the state of your "universal pointer" class should not be a *template*. Templates do things at compile-time, not runtime.

Your class should be a discriminated union:

```
template<class T>
class pointer
{
public:
  T* get() const
  {
    if(is_raw)
    {
      return const_cast<T*>(ptr.p);
    }
    return ptr.sp.get();
  }

private:
  union ptr_union
  {
    T *p = nullptr;
    shared_ptr<T> sp;
  };

  bool is_raw;
  ptr_union ptr;
};
```

The class itself *tracks* which kind of pointer it currently is. You should be able to assign it a `shared_ptr<T>` value, and it will become a `shared_ptr<T>`. If you assign it a `T*`, it becomes a `T*`. And so forth.

This way, your prospective `func` isn't a template anymore:

```
void func(pointer<std::string> s);
```

It's a concrete class.

---

BTW: note that such classes are usually a bad idea. Smart pointers exist to specify ownership. If a function takes a smart pointer, that represents a transfer of ownership. If a function does not take a smart pointer, that represents a *lack* of transfer of ownership.

For a function to take a pointer that may *or may not* be owned is very... odd. It's not entirely unhelpful in corner cases. But it is not a normal thing, and should certainly not be used *frequently*.

Comment: what if I determine at compiletime wheather a pointer is reference counted or raw. then I could do this with templates, coundnt I?

Comment: @Exagon "*what if I determine at compiletime wheather a pointer is reference counted or raw.*" Then you should be using the type `T*` or `shared_ptr<T>` based on that determination. I can't explain anything more without knowing something about the template metaprogramming code that makes this determination.